# Issues related with Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to wpf and i am working on first application i have some issues related with this

1.)Control allignment : My controls when set on the page is seem ok but when i run my application controls slightly change their position.

2.)Resolution Issue : When i try to run application on the machine with different resolutions some controls become invisible.

3.)Bind combobox :When i try to bind combobox with static or dynamic combobox items i am not able to get first item on page load for eg if i have a city combobox then i want to show "Select City" on page load.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any specific samples of where things are going wrong? The question is too general for most of us to help you out with your problem.

Comment: Hello @W.Meints i can give you one eg for 3 point like
 <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,182,0,0" Name="cmbPercentage" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" Text="Select percentage">
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi1">100%</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi2">50%</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
this is my combobox but i didn't get "Select Percentage" text on page load

Comment: If you can edit your question to be much more narrow and specific, please flag it for moderator review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. WPF has its own alignment system that differs from those in WinForms and HTML. Be sure to study the issue before doing any markup - trust me, you will just lose time.
2. WPF is resolution independent - it's one of the most essential of its features. The problem should be related to the 1st one.
3. Could you provide additional info so that I can figure out what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

There are lots of resources on WPF. I would recommend visiting [Wpf Tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/). And for more serious reading [Pro WPF in C# 2010 (by Matthew MacDonald)](http://www.apress.com/9781430272052) is great.

Comment: i can give you one eg for 3 point like <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,182,0,0" Name="cmbPercentage" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" Text="Select percentage"> <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi1">100%</ComboBoxItem> <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi2">50%</ComboBoxItem> </ComboBox> this is my combobox but i didn't get "Select Percentage" text on page load

Answer (score 0):

**1 & 2)** As EvAlex says, WPF has it's own alignment system using various `Panel` types. These grow and shrink content to take advantage of the available space and resolution.

You appear to be dragging controls onto the form in DevStudio, which is adding all those `Margin="323,182,0,0"` properties to you markup. This is effectively hardcoding an absolute position for your controls which is generally a bad idea.

**3)** You cannot set text in a WPF combo unless it is in the list of items or you have set `IsEditable="True"`.

Read some of the tutorials that EvAlex posted. You need to get a good grasp of the basic ideas before jumping in. WPF does have a fairly steep learning curve.